# SOAPUI: running load tests using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

Using soapUI free version(5.4.0). I have simple project with test-case which has test-steps and load-tests like:

```
TestCase
  Test-steps
    one
    two

  LoadTests
    LoadOne
    LoadTwo
```

I want to run `LoadOne` and `LoadTwo` load tests, using Groovy scripting, in separate script. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're executing a Groovy test step from the same project, the following script will execute a load test called `LoadOne`:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.loadtest.*;

// Get the load test
def loadTest = testRunner.testCase.getLoadTestByName("LoadOne");

// Run the load test
WsdlLoadTestRunner loadTestRunner = new WsdlLoadTestRunner(loadTest);
loadTestRunner.start(true);
loadTestRunner.waitUntilFinished();
```

Then, of course, do the same for your other load test.